# How to display only randomly 'filled in' textfields in a `UILabel`?

Tags: objective-c

I have a working random app. It consists of 10 `UITextFields`, a `UILabel` and a `UIButton`.
Basic idea is to fill in usernames in the `UITextFields` and via the `UIButton` randomly choose a name. It works well, but if for the occasion only 6 usernames are joining in, what about the other 4 `UITextFields`? How can I rule them out for the random list or array?
I hope you can help me, thanks for looking into this matter!

Here is my m file:

```
     #import "ViewController.h"

    @interface ViewController ()
    - (IBAction)random:(id)sender;
     @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *naam;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *naam2;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *naam3;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *naam4;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *naam5;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *naam6;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *naam7;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *naam8;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *naam9;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *naam10;


    @end  

    @implementation ViewController

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    - (IBAction)random:(id)sender 
    {
        int text;
        text = rand() %10;
        switch (text) {
              case 0:
                    self.userName = self.naam2.text;
                    break;
              case 1:
                    self.userName = self.naam.text;
                    break;
              case 2:
                    self.userName = self.naam3.text;
                    break;
              case 3:
                    self.userName = self.naam4.text;
                    break;
              case 4:
                    self.userName = self.naam5.text;
                    break;
              case 5:
                    self.userName = self.naam6.text;
                    break;
              case 6:
                    self.userName = self.naam7.text;
                    break;
              case 7:
                    self.userName = self.naam8.text;
                    break;
              case 8:
                    self.userName = self.naam9.text;
                    break;
              case 9:
                    self.userName = self.naam10.text;
                    break;
              default:
                    break;
         }

         NSString *nameString = self.userName;
         if ([nameString length] == 0 ) {
             nameString = @"Wie?";
         }

         NSString *random = [[NSString alloc]
                    initWithFormat: @"De Bob is....%@!", nameString];
         self.label.text = random;
    }

    - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn: (UITextField *)theTextField {
        if (theTextField == self.naam) {
            [theTextField resignFirstResponder];
        } else if (theTextField == self.naam2) {
            [theTextField resignFirstResponder];   
        } else if (theTextField == self.naam3) { 
            [theTextField resignFirstResponder];   
        } else if (theTextField == self.naam4) {
            [theTextField resignFirstResponder];   
        } else if (theTextField == self.naam5) {
            [theTextField resignFirstResponder];   
        } else if (theTextField == self.naam6) {
            [theTextField resignFirstResponder];   
        } else if (theTextField == self.naam7) {
            [theTextField resignFirstResponder];   
        } else if (theTextField == self.naam8) {
            [theTextField resignFirstResponder];   
        } else if (theTextField == self.naam9) {
            [theTextField resignFirstResponder];   
        } else if (theTextField == self.naam10) {
            [theTextField resignFirstResponder];   
        }
        return YES;
    }

    @end
```

Comment: Welcome to the stackoverflow. Please make sure you tag your questions correctly not just so it helps you get the best answer possible but to help other users in the future. Also check your code formatting I have corrected this best possible to make it more readable just make sure we can read it next time. I struggled to understand your code snippets because they were formatted wrong. Also if you find an answer that has helped you resolve your issue please accept it user like to get credit for there work.

Answer (score 0):

You should create UITextField runtime.

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 200, 300, 40)];
textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
textField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
textField.placeholder = @"enter text";
textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;    
textField.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:textField];
```

This will make sure not unnecessary textFields are there.

Alternatively, in viewDidLoad method set each one hidden to YES. And based on number of players setHidden to NO.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Anoob, I am a very newbie in obj C, so forgive me, if I don't understand how to create UITextfields runtime,Do you have an example?

Comment: Thanks again Anoop for your fast reply, I will let you know if this works, greets Jonomato

Comment: UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] error initializer element  is not a compile-time constant                 initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 200, 300, 40)];
I think has something to do with init, right?

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest that you first create an `NSMutableArray` or `NSArray` depending on the implementation, containing only the values of the filled-in usernames and then use `randomIndex = arc4random() % [theArray count];` to pick a name from the array.

Here is a possible implementation, but not optimal:

```
NSMutableArray *usernamesList = [NSMutableArray array];

for (UIView *view in [self.view subviews]) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
        UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)view;
        if (![textField.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
            [usernamesList addObject:view];
        }
    }

    NSUInteger index = arc4random() % [usernamesList count];
    NSLog(@"The chosen name is %@", [usernamesList objectAtIndex:index]);
}
```

To be able to iterate only through the textfields for the usernames, a better solution is to use `IBOutletCollection`

Comment: For a better random repartition prefer the use of `arc4random_uniform()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Zaphod, Since your advise takes some time to test, I can give you the results later

Answer (score 0):

Just do a for in loop and check to see if the text of that label is empty like this:
    int count = 0;
    for(UITextField* textf in [self.view subviews]{
        if(textf isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]){
            if(![textf text] isEqualToString:@""]{
               [textf setText:@"Some string"];
               textf.tag = count;
               count++;
            }
        ]
    }

After this, just get a random number:
     NSUInteger index = arc4random() % [array count];

If you want to get say ten random numbers, just put that in a for loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    NSUInteger index = arc4random() % [array count];
    //Loop through text fields again and get the one with the tag that matches the random number
}
```

For in loops are pretty handy because you don't have to have iterators like normal for loops and you also don't have to know the number of objects you're iterating over. It's all taken care of for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, shadow. I tried it but it failed. I must admit I lack understanding of Xcode  coz I am a very newbie on this.

Comment: Here I'll edit my answer with some more sample code so you can get a better idea of what to do.